# Finding matches in a matrix of cells against a second worksheet

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I'm attempting to generate a matrix of people who are in common with each other.  In one worksheet, I have the matrix itself, and in the other, I have the raw data.  The output needed is to put an "x" in the cell if there's a match, or nothing if there isn't a match.

Here is a sample of the matrix worksheet, where the names going down in column A are the same names going across in row 1.  Names are in "firstname middlename lastname" format (usually):

```
   A     | B     | C     | D     | E    
 ------------------------------------
1|       | Name1 | Name2 | Name3 | Name4
2| Name1 |       |       |       |
3| Name2 |       |       |       |
4| Name3 |       |       |       |
5| Name4 |       |       |       |
```

Here is a sample of the raw data worksheet.  Column A is a sorted list of names, and column B is who they are on common with.  There are hundreds of names in the list:

```
   A     | B     
 ------------------------------------
1| Name1 | Name33
2| Name1 | Name5
3| Name1 | Name21
4| Name2 | Name1
5| Name2 | Name92
...
```

The formula I need to write goes into the blank cells in the matrix worksheet.  Here is an example of the final output (though there are many more names in the actual matrix):

```
   A     | B     | C     | D     | E    
 ------------------------------------
1|       | Name1 | Name2 | Name3 | Name4
2| Name1 |       |       | x     | x
3| Name2 | x     |       | x     |
4| Name3 | x     | x     |       |
5| Name4 |       |       | x     |
```

Here's how far I've gotten before hitting a brick wall.  I attempted to write a VLOOKUP formula to do this, but it wouldn't work if I just told it to look in the entire range of the raw data worksheet because it would pick up matches from the wrong people.  I only want it to match against the part of column B that had the name in Column A for that cell.

So, the closest I could get was to put in the specific range from the raw data file for the name listed on that particular row in the matrix.  For instance, I manually looked up Name1 in column A of the raw data file and found it existed in rows 39-62.  So, for Name1, if one of the names going across row 1 of the matrix is found between rows 39-62 of column B in Raw_Data, mark an "x":

```
=IF(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B$1,Raw_Data!$B39:$B62,1,FALSE),"")="","","x")
```

This would work only for one row in my matrix sheet.  Then, when going to the next row, I'd have to manually look up the Raw_Data rows for that person and put it in the formula.  Granted, it saved a little time, but not nearly as much as if I could get this formula to work across the whole matrix without any changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this COUNTIFS formula in B2 copied across and down

`=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(Raw_Data!$A:$A,IF({1,0},B$1,$A2),Raw_Data!$B:$B,IF({0,1},B$1,$A2))),"X","")`

COUNTIFS counts when the B1 name is in col A of Raw_data and A2 name in Col B....or vice versa. If the count if > 0 then there's a match and you get "x"

I'm assuming that you always want the "x"s to appear in both boxes.....but in your example you only show the names in one, e.g. Name2/Name1 is shown with "x" but not the other way round - if that's the way it should be then it's a simpler COUNTIFS like this:

`=IF(COUNTIFS(Raw_Data!$A:$A,$A2,Raw_Data!$B:$B,B$1),"X","")`

Comment: That's it!  Thank you!  I only needed the simpler formula, since, in my raw data file, any names appearing in the second column will be duplicated in the first column.  This is the first time I've used stackoverflow and you were very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve this by using array formulas. Basically what you need to do is to create a key using the names (row and column) and do the same thing on the reference table in your formula. Then if there is 1+ match(es) you put an x.

```
=IF(SUM(IF(OR($A2&B$1=$F$1:$F$2&$G$1:$G$2;$A2&B$1=$G$1:$G$2&$F$1:$F$2);1))>=1;"x";"")
```

As always, when using array formulas you need to press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER in the formula bar for the formula to calculate properly.

[image]

Comment: I had difficulty implementing this solution, but another solution was presented soon afterwards that I was able to use.  Thank you for assisting, though!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are much more elegant solutions, but this would be very easy if you added a helper column.

[image: Concat values]

Then you could just use `Countif` against both versions of the concatenated strings

[image: Countif]

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!$D:$D,B$1&"|"&$A2)+COUNTIF(Sheet1!$D:$D,$A2&"|"&B$1)>0,"x","")
```

Comment: This one worked for me, but another answer came in that didn't require the helper column.  Thanks!

Comment: No problems. I knew that it wouldn't take Barry long to turn up and post the proper solution :-)